# How to enable reports for GCM in google developer console?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am not able to see the reports of GCM in statistics provided by google developer console.

Here is the screenshot attached :

[image]

Please help me how can I enable reporting of GCM in developer console, like how many notifications were sent and received by the devices.

When I click on the dropdown I can see the following options . I cant see GCM Message and GCM Registrations in My dropdown . Dont know what I am missing . Is there any thing that I should enable ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update :** GCM is not available anymore on the console. Use FCM instead. <sup>Thank you for the update satyajit and Ignacio Soler Garcia</sup>

[**GCM is deprecated :**](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#stats) As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features.

---

To view statistics and any error messages for your GCM applications:

> - Go to the [Developer Console](http://play.google.com/apps/publish).
> - Login with your developer account.
> - You will see a page that has a list of all of your apps.
> - Click on the "statistics" link next to the app for which you want to view GCM stats.
> - Now you are on the statistics page.
> - Go to the drop-down menu and select the GCM metric you want to view.

**Note:** *Stats on the Google API Console are not enabled for GCM. You must use the [Developer Console.](http://play.google.com/apps/publish)*

---

Reference : [***Viewing Statistics***](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#stats)

Comment: See I have updated a screenshot which shows the dropdown . In my case its not showing GCM Metrics . Is there anything I need to enable so that I can have Gcm Metrics in the dropdown.

Comment: When did you publish the app which uses GCM? Before a day?

Comment: No its been more than 2 months !!! Notifications are working fine but I am not able to see the metrics .

Comment: And the page you created for GCM to get project_id etc, is the same google id (which you used as developer account) ?

Comment: @lakshay We need to create a project using a Gmail account on developer console for GCM. So is that the same account which you are using as publisher account?

Comment: @lakshay Most welcome. Please do not forget to add your comment after your final analysis. That would be very helpful for other users :)

Comment: If your project is using GCM still and not FCM, they are not showing any stats.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia Thank you for the update. Answer updated.